# Euler's Solution of Seven Bridges of Königsberg in Layman Terms

Tags: graph-theory

Is the below brief explanation correct and complete (at least in context)? Can it be improved/simplified without getting technical? I am especially concerned about the last sentence: Is that reasoning absolutely clear to a layman?

[image]

> > The problem can be viewed as drawing the above graph without lifting your hand and without retracing a line. Observe that each dot is connected by three lines. Also observe that you have to draw a line to arrive at a dot, and you have to draw a line to leave that dot. Because each dot is connected by three lines, each must be visited twice. But it is impossible to visit each dot twice (even number of times) and end up with each dot connected with three lines (odd number of times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen and taught this so many times, it's hard to view it as a layman again.  I agree with you that the last line is troublesome, because one of the dots has five lines.  Here's how I might have explained it

Each dot is exited as many times as it is entered, except possibly the starting dot ( which may have one more exit than entrance ) and the ending dot ( which may have one more entrance than exit ).  So, with at most two exceptions, every dot has as many entrances as exists, so it has an even number of lines.  But in the Konigsberg graph, there are more than two dots with an odd number of edges.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that your final sentence is less clear than it could be. Instead of the last two sentences, I would say:

"So visiting a dot other than at the start or finish adds two lines to it. So any dot with an odd number of lines at it must be either the start or the finish. But there are four dots with odd numbers of lines, so this is impossible."

Comment: Thak you, user73985.

Answer (score 0):

When I teach this problem, I say something along the lines of:

Entering and leaving an area requires two of the paths. Thus, entering and leaving an area any number of times will require an even number of paths to that area; we will only cross an odd number of paths if we either start or end at that area. As we only start and end one time each, at most two areas can have an odd number of paths; since four actually do, the problem is unsolvable.